# MongoDB nested Object field depth limit

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If we have the following JavaScript object:

```
var obj = {

  field: {
           field: {
                    field: {
                              field: {...}
                            }
                  }
          }
          }
```

how deep can MongoDB go?

Comment: I think it can go until you hit the 16MB document size limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In accordance with the official [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) MongoDB supports 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents. Beside this there's a size limitation for a single document which is 16 megabytes.

If you are interested in storing larger documents you should read about [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/).

Comment: Any idea of how can we limit this let say the depth of 3 levels?