# How to fix this issue "MongoCommandException: Command insert failed: BSONObj exceeded maximum nested object depth: 200."

Tags: c#, mongodb

The Max depth of the json is more than 200 due to which while inserting data into mongo Db its failing with above error..
Any help would be appreciated

I tried setting this value :

BsonDefaults.MaxSerializationDepth = 1000;

but no luck has the Bson document Max is 200 ..

Comment: the officially recommended by mongoDB depth is  100  ( https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/ ) even in some cases up to 200 is possible: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10578

Answer (score 0):

The [official advice](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Nested-Depth-for-BSON-Documents) is still the case that you should restrict your use cases to `100 levels` of nesting or less; the server just happens to allow for some slack.

Similar answers on the stackoverflow:

- [What is the Maximum Depth of Embedded Documents Allowed in
  MongoDb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617933/what-is-the-maximum-depth-of-embedded-documents-allowed-in-mongodb)
- [MongoDB nested Object field depth limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576704/mongodb-nested-object-field-depth-limit)